# Steady State for a Transition Matrix in a Markov Chain Question

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains, markov-process

> *There are two boxes. The red box contains four red marbles and one blue marble, and
> the blue box contains five blue marbles and three red marbles. The following experiment is
> done a hundred times: A marble is randomly drawn from one of the boxes, its color recorded,
> then replaced in the same box. The first drawing is from the red box, but each subsequent
> drawing is determined by the color of the marble most recently drawn: if it is red, the next
> drawing comes from the red box; if it is blue, the next drawing comes from the blue box.
> What is the probability the hundredth marble is red?*

From the question, I calculate

$$P(Red | Red)= \frac{4}{5}=0.8, P(Red | Blue)= \frac{1}{5}=0.2,...$$

I use the above probabilities to set up a transition matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
0.8 & 0.2 \\
0.375 & 0.675
\end{bmatrix}

Since the question is asking for the hundredth marble, I know that I am looking for a steady state. In a steady state, the probability of red in next ball is the same as the probability of red in this ball. If $P(r)=Probability of Red$, then:
$$\frac{4}{5}r+\frac{1}{5}(1-r)=r\implies r=\frac{15}{23}$$

This also matches what I found by raising the transition matrix to the twentieth power.

However, is there anything else I need to show? In particular, what is the general condition for a transition matrix to have a steady state? And how do I show that this matrix in particular will achieve a steady state.